# Barometer altitude calculation

Tags: quadcopter, sensors, imu

I want to calculate altitude using a barometer which is mounted in the proximity of a number of components which get quite hot and raise the localised temperature. The barometric pressure [equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometric_formula) is dependent on temperature. Most typical mem’s barometers come with an internal temperature sensor - I assume to allow calculation of altitude. However, would the altitude calculation using the barometric pressure equation be incorrect if this calculated using the internal temperature sensor influenced by the localised heating from other devices? Is a temperature reading of the external temperature needed? If the localised temperature effects do influence the altitude calculation then it would necessitate that I remove the components which heat up from the proximity of the barometer or take an external temperature reading at distance unaffected by the localised heating?

Comment: you only need to monitor the temperature of the sensor itself

Comment: Hi @jsotola, thanks for your comment. Could you explain why only the temperature of the sensor itself is needed - or point me to a link which explains this? My confusion lies in the barometric equation temperature which is dependent on lapse rates - I had assumed these lapse rates were determined by the external air temperature, which after a certain altitude becomes constant and then you switch to a different equation. But if the temperature of the device is swamped by a local heating effect it could also effectively be considered constant and would only require one of the equations.

Comment: i misunderstood your post ... i thought that the sensor is sensitive to temperature changes ... that is why i said that you only need to measure the temperature of the sensor ... i know that air pressure is affected by temperature, but i did not know that the absolute measured pressure value is not barometric pressure ... it actually makes no sense to me ... maybe it goes back to days of mercury filled barometers